# creating a subtotal based on multiple columns in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I am working in SSRS 2008 R2 and need to create a subtotal in a report based on two columns.  For example, I need to subtotal a spend amount based on Cost Center and Account Number.  This seems like a simple enough requirement but I am at a standstill.

Sample data:

```
Business Segment   Company Code  Cost Center  Account  Ship Date    Ship to   Ship From  Total Amount
Home Furnishing    1008          1234567890    11111    1/1/2013    Tailspin  Contoso      123.45
Baby/Parenting     1536          2234567890    22222    12/31/2012  Bobs Bait Jims Tackle  543.21
Kitchen Appliances 2553          3234567890    33333    11/11/1999  Ajax      Acme         1000.99
```

I need to provide a subtotal based on Company Code, Cost Center and Account.

Comment: What is your Dataset? Can you supply some example data? What should the end result be?

Comment: The data set looks like this: Business Segment, Company Code, Cost Center, Account, Ship Date, Ship to , Ship From, Total Amount. I need to provide a subtotal based on Company Code, Cost Center and Account.

Comment: Sample data for Business Segment: Home Furnishing, Baby/Parenting, Kitchen Appliances; for Company Code: 1008, 1536, 2553; Cost Center: 10 digit numeric; Account: 5 digit numeric, ShipDate: date product shipped, and Ship To and Ship From are company names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're grouping on multiple rows, just create groups for each of these rows, but only display totals in a header or footer for the lowest level group.

For example, I've created a simplified **Dataset** based on yours:

[image]

I've created a **Tablix** and added groups for *Cost Center* and *Account Number*. However, I only included a group footer row for the *Account Number* group. In this footer I've added the summed *Total Amount* for the *Cost Center* / *Account Number* combination. It looks something like this in the designer:

[image]

The end result looks like this; it's displaying each individual row in the **Dataset** plus totals for each *Cost Center* / *Account Number* combination:

[image]